# set color limits in python colormap

Tags: matplotlib

I need to display data from a 2D matrix in a gray colormap, but I need to define it in such a gray scale that white and black are not the colors for the min and max values of the matrix, in order to not saturate the image. What I need is a gray scale colormap with gray levels between 20% and 70%, with at least 20% difference between the levels of gray. Any suggestions?
I'm using the imshow task form matplotlib.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Did you solve your problem? 
I guess this is what you want, try this:

all code in pylab mode:

```
a = np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)
#here is the image with white and black end
imshow(a,cmap=mat.cm.binary)
colorbar()

#we extract only the 0.2-->0.7 part of original colormap and make a new one
#so that the white and black end are removed
rgba_array = mat.cm.binary(np.linspace(0,1,num=10,endpoint=True))
extract_rgba_array_255 = rgba_array[2:8,0:3]
imshow(a,cmap=mat.colors.ListedColormap(extract_rgba_array_255))
colorbar()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this either by creating a [custom color](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html) map with colors your prefer, or by using the [`vmin`, `vmax`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow) keywords in `imshow` to force a larger range on the colorbar than you want to use in your plot.

Comment: I tried that... but in defining a dictionary, RBG colors must go from 0.0 to 1.0, so at the end I will still have the "absolut" white ad black colors.... right? and I tried setting vmin=0.2 and vmax=0.7 and there was no change at all... even with norm=None in the imshow parameters  :(  what can I do?